# TTStyledTextLabel transparent background

Tags: iphone, three20

I posted this on the three20 google group, but then saw the recommendation to post here?

I'm not getting anywhere with getting the background of this object to be transparent.

```
TTStyledTextLabel* label1 = [[[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1250)] autorelease];    
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.dataSource = [TTListDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
                       label1,
                       nil];
```

I'm doing this in a TTTableViewController.

I've tried overriding the class, but nothing I do in there helps. I've also tried overriding TTListDataSource and trying to set values there, but all I'm able to do is overwrite the contents with a new cell, which I can get to be transparent, but then it's no longer a TTStyledTextLabel.

Doing `label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` sets it to transparent, but there appears to be some object behind it which remains white. If I change `label1.backgroundColor` to red it works.

I've done this with TTTableImageItemCell and TTTableSubtitleItemCell with success, but TTStyledTextLabel doesn't seem to use TTStyledTextTableItemCell.

I'm really lost. Can someone please tell me what needs to be set to clearColor to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `TTTableViewController`? try editing the default style sheet and change the default  color from white to clear:

https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/689/files

Comment: That didn't do it unfortunately. TTStyledTextLabel is placed in a TTTableViewController, yes. There are several colorWithWhite calls in TTDefaultStyleSheet which I might have to play with though.

Comment: No, still not getting it. Nothing I do changes it. Sigh.